# Add link in google fusiontable

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

Is it possible to put active link in fusiontables row? Neither https://stackoverflow.com/ nor  Text  works. But I`ve seen active links in other tables.
Column type is text/string.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit > Change Columns and click on the column you designated as to be a link. Type should be Text and Format should be Link.

Let me know if you have any issues or need further clarification.